# Let $A=\{1,2,\dots,100\}$, $B_k$ is subset of $A$ have $k$ element so that sum of two arbitrary elements of $B_k$ isn't divisible by its difference.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{1,2,\dots,100\}$ and let $B_k$ be a subset of $A$ having $k$ elements so that the sum of two arbitrary elements of $B_k$ isn't divisible by its difference. Find the largest value of $k$.

I figured it out $k$ is 34, but I can't prove it is largest.

$B_k= \{1,4,7,10,13,16,...,100\}=\{3k-2\mid k=1,2,\dots,34\}$

This is how I prove that the sum of two arbitrary elements of $B_k$ isn't divisible by its difference:

Let $b_n$ and $b_m$ $(n<m)$ is elements of the subset $B_k$. Then $b_n$ is in the form $3n+1$ and $b_m$ is in the form $3m+1$. Then its sum is $3(m+n)+2\equiv 
 2\pmod 3$ and its difference is $3(m-n)\equiv0\pmod3$.

Comment: @joriki yes, sorry for the grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k\geq35$ then it is *unescapable* that $B_k$ contains two elements $a,b$ with $b-a\in\{1,2\}$, but:

- If $b-a=1$ then $b-a\mid b+a$.
- If $b-a=2$ then $b+a=b-a+2a=2(1+a)$ so that $b-a\mid b+a$.

So we conclude that $k\leq34$ and your effort shows that $k\geq34$.

Final conclusion: $k=34$.

Answer (score 2):

Now note that you cannot have any two elements with a difference of $1$ or $2$, so no such set can contain more than $34$ elements.